# Can I use logs to solve an equation formatted as $a^x + b^x = z$

Tags: functions, logarithms, exponential-function

For instance, I know that in $4^x + 5^x = 41$  ; $x = 2$

I tried doing $x[\log(4) + \log(5)] = \log(41)$, but that's not right.

Is there anyway to solve this using logs. I think there's a way to solve it by graphing but I wanted to see if I can do it on paper alone.

Thank you!

Comment: There is no formula for the logarithm of a sum.

Comment: Expanding on Peter's comment, it is not generally true that $\log (a + b) = \log a + \log b$, which you assume in your second equation.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that. I knew that wasn't "allowed' but it was the only thing I could think of. I did graph it and the intersect point is x = 2

Comment: Reducing the equation mod $5$ here tells you that whatever the possible solution is, it must be an even number.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can not.

By the way,  $f(x)=4^x+5^x$ increases  and we get an unique root: $2$.

Comment: When you say a unique root, are you referencing the intersect point on the graph?

Comment: @estevao Yes, a graph of $f$ and the line $y=41$ have an unique common point $(2,41),$ which says our equation has an unique root.